# I am confused by this javafx ActionEvent code

Tags: javafx, actionevent

According to this code, button("enlarge") will trigger an action which is calling the method enlarge(), which will do:      circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() + 2);

which is just merely changing the radius value. what I don't understand is that how merely changing the radius will somehow make the program redraw the entire circle.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ControlCircle extends Application {

private CirclePane1 circlePane = new CirclePane1();
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.setSpacing(10);
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Button btEnlarge = new Button("Enlarge");
Button btShrink = new Button("Shrink");
hBox.getChildren().add(btEnlarge);
hBox.getChildren().add(btShrink);

btEnlarge.setOnAction(new EnlargeHandler());
btShrink.setOnAction(new ShrinkHandler());

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setCenter(circlePane);
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);

Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 200, 150);
primaryStage.setTitle("ControlCircle");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

}

class EnlargeHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        circlePane.enlarge();
    }
}

class ShrinkHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        circlePane.shrink();
    }
    }

}

class CirclePane1 extends StackPane{
private Circle circle = new Circle(50);

public CirclePane1() {

    getChildren().add(circle);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
}

public void enlarge() {
    circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() + 2);

}

public void shrink() {
    circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() > 2 ? circle.getRadius() - 2 
: circle.getRadius());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of `Circle` you can see how the `radius` property is defined:

```
private final DoubleProperty radius = new DoublePropertyBase() {

    @Override
    public void invalidated() {
        NodeHelper.markDirty(Circle.this, DirtyBits.NODE_GEOMETRY);
        NodeHelper.geomChanged(Circle.this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return Circle.this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "radius";
    }
};
```

When you change the value of the `radius` property its `invalidated()` method is called. And this is where the "magic" happens, it calls these two methods:

```
    NodeHelper.markDirty(Circle.this, DirtyBits.NODE_GEOMETRY);
    NodeHelper.geomChanged(Circle.this);
```

Now, I don't know what these methods do *specifically* - nor do I have the time/desire to study it - but they tell the JavaFX runtime that the `Circle` needs to be redrawn. This means that the next time a rendering pulse occurs, which may be triggered by these methods, the `Circle` will be drawn with its new radius.

This is all very optimized and will cause a redraw only when applicable (such as only when part of a`scene-graph`).